# matplotlib: generating vector plot

Tags: matplotlib, vector-graphics

I want to generate a vector plot with matplotlib. I tried hard - but the output is a raster image. Here's what I use:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

and finally:

```
myfig.savefig('myfig.eps', format='eps')
```

I've found that export to `ps` gives a vector image, but the problem with `eps` remains.

Comment: Can you give an example (make up some data if you need to) of the actual calls to `plt`? This will help others contribute.

Comment: I am confident that the problem you are describing is not as you suggest and that the eps output really is a fully fledged vector rendition. It may be that you are looking at the eps through a poor viewer - which application are you using to view the eps?

Comment: `plt.savefig('some_name.eps', bbox_inches='tight')` produces a vectorized plot on my system.

Answer (score 21):

I use the following code:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots() # or 
fig.savefig('filename.eps', format='eps')
```

Answer (score 9):

If you need emf files as output format, e.g. to insert high quality plots into ms word/powerpoint and you are willing to use inkscape as converter you can apply this solution:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import subprocess, os

def plot_as_emf(figure, **kwargs):
    inkscape_path = kwargs.get('inkscape', "C://Program Files//Inkscape//inkscape.exe")
    filepath = kwargs.get('filename', None)

    if filepath is not None:
        path, filename = os.path.split(filepath)
        filename, extension = os.path.splitext(filename)

        svg_filepath = os.path.join(path, filename+'.svg')
        emf_filepath = os.path.join(path, filename+'.emf')

        figure.savefig(svg_filepath, format='svg')

        subprocess.call([inkscape_path, svg_filepath, '--export-emf', emf_filepath])
        os.remove(svg_filepath)
```

In order to test this function you can run a simple example:

```
plt.plot([1,2], [4,5])
fig = plt.gcf()
plot_as_emf(fig, filename="C:/test.emf")
```

Answer (score 5):

Can try for svg format:

```
plt.savefig("filepath.svg", format = 'svg', dpi=300)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try exporting as a pdf or svg as described in http://neuroscience.telenczuk.pl/?p=331
If you need an eps the pdf2ps command works great.

Comment: That website has all broken image links at the moment.

Comment: I used waybackmachine to get the previous snapshots: https://web.archive.org/web/20230205040301/https://datascience.telenczuk.pl/publication-quality-figures-with-matplotlib-and-svgutils/