# python - matplotlib - segmentation fault with figsize

Tags: python, matplotlib

I don't understand why if I uncomment line 3 of the following code

```
from matplotlib import pyplot

pyplot.clf()
#pyplot.figure(figsize=(400, 200))
pyplot.plot(range(0,len(x)),x,label="x")
pyplot.legend(loc='best', fancybox=True, shadow=True)
pyplot.savefig("/home/user/ooo.png", dpi=600)
```

I get a Segmentation fault (core dumped) error. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: `figsize` is in inches! I can imagine that matploblib runs out of memory for a 400x200 inch figure at 600 dpi.. Does it work with a more normal figure size, lets say 10x10 inch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

400 inches by 200 inches is too big, so you may want to reduce the figure size.

If you need to scale your image, I recommend to save it in a vector format (see [matplotlib: generating vector plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9266150/matplotlib-generating-vector-plot)).